# Frases del tipo "¡Que + el verbo en subjuntivo …!" desde el punto de vista sintáctico (deseo, pedido, maldición)

Tags: sintaxis

¿Cómo se debe considerar las frases del tipo **¡Que + el verbo en subjuntivo …!** desde el punto de vista sintáctico?

> ¡Que tengas un buen día!
>
> ¡Que te mueras!

Yo pensaba que se trata de frases sintácticamente autónomas (elipsis; omitiendo la oración principal (*quiero que/deseo que* …) pero una de mis compañeras de estudios dice que tengo que ponerlas en el apartado de mi presentación sobre oraciones completivas:

> (Quiero) ¡Que te vaya bien!

Tengo la sensación de que yo tengo razón pero no puedo justificar mi opinion =( 
Heeelp por favor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En el caso de oraciones como:

> ¡Que tengas un buen día!
>
> ¡Que te mueras!
>
> ¡Que te vaya bien!

no creo que hablar de elipsis verbal y de oraciones completivas sea mutuamente excluyente: hay elipsis verbal y hay una subordinada sustantiva (o completiva) que, al omitirse el verbo que la introduce, se convierte en una **oración independiente introducida por *que***.

Creo que en tu presentación, Aurora, deberías hablar de esas oraciones que expresan deseo o maldición como un **subtipo de oraciones independientes introducidas por *que***.

En academia.edu, he encontrado [una interesante tesis](https://www.academia.edu/12276186/Oraciones_independientes_introducidas_por_que_estructura_y_significado) titulada: "Oraciones independientes introducidas por *que*: estructura y significado", de Valentina Asenjo Valenzuela.

En su parte introductoria, esta tesis hace una síntesis de cómo se clasifican las oraciones independientes introducidas por "que" según diferentes autores, que transcribo a continuación (no incluyo la nueva tipología que propone la autora a los efectos de la tesis):

> 3.2.1.1. Para Porroche Ballesteros (2000: 101) existe un primer tipo de oraciones independientes introducidas por *que* y es aquel que tiene la función de expresar mandato o deseo, y se presenta en dos posibles ocasiones: cuando se formula un mandato a un tercero y cuando se repite una instrucción anteriormente formulada:
>
> ```
>     (11) a) Que se vayan.
>
>          b) Que te calles. (después de haberle ordenado que se callara dos o tres veces)
> ```
>
> Pons Bordería (2003: 537), por su parte, establece una categorización en la que se señala que en casos como estos se hablará de órdenes. A diferencia de lo propuesto por Porroche (2000), para Pons Bordería (2003) estos enunciados se clasifican de forma independiente y no en la misma categoría que los deseos, que para el autor pertenecen a la misma categoría que las maldiciones, con ejemplos como:
>
> ```
>     (12) Que te aproveche.
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> 3.2.1.3. Otra posibilidad de aparición de oraciones independientes introducidas por *que* es cuando están en relación con otros enunciados.
>
> Para Muñoz Medrano (2005: 249) estas oraciones pueden contener una referencia explícita al enunciado que los precede –en ese caso se habla de *que* reiterativo– o pueden comentar el enunciado al que acompañan, por ejemplo:
>
> ```
>     (14) – No es mi amiga.
>
>          – ¿Que no es tu amiga? Será ahora. (C. Martín Gaite, 2001: 115)
> ```
>
> En el texto se cita a Cascón Martín (1995: 154-160 en Muñoz 2005: 249), quien llama “ilativo” a este tipo de *que*; además se señala que este uso tiene la finalidad de “encabezar expresiones que suponen una reacción de desacuerdo, protesta, reproche o sorpresa con respecto a las palabras, en parte repetidas, del interlocutor”. Para Pons
>   Bordería (2003: 537) ejemplos de exclamaciones como la que sigue son representativos de este tipo de uso:
>
> ```
>     (15) ¡Que gaste ese dinero en tonterías!
> ```
>
> 3.2.1.4. Uno de los usos del *que* átono como introductor de oraciones independientes más destacado por los autores revisados es aquel que dice relación con el refuerzo del propio discurso. Para Pons Bordería (2003: 537) este uso corresponde a réplicas enfáticas; según Muñoz Medrano (2005: 248) en estos casos hablamos de un *que* que imprime mayor fuerza a la expresión. Para la autora, en estos casos *que*, como otros marcadores discursivos, “ha modificado el significado y algunas de las particularidades distribucionales que lo caracterizan en la sintaxis oracional, pasando a desempeñar una función discursiva”. Porroche Ballesteros (2000: 103), por su parte, propone que en estos casos la partícula *que* puede enfatizar el propio discurso, sin que este se relacione a ningún otro enunciado y, además, puede hacer referencia a un enunciado anterior o bien comentar el enunciado al que acompaña. Ambas opciones se ven ilustradas en los ejemplos que siguen:
>
> ```
> (16) a) Que ya está apagado. (ante alguien que intenta apagar lo que es obvio que no está encendido)
>
>      b) – ¿A dónde va a ir ese, si no tiene un peso?
>         – ¿Que no tiene un peso? Está forrado en plata.
> ```
>
> Este último tipo de enunciados, para Pons Bordería (2003: 535) se relacionan con las oraciones interrogativas directas del tipo:
>
> ```
> (16) c) – Allí probé el smörgasbord
>         – ¿Que probaste el qué?
> ```
>
> 3.2.1.5. Otra categoría en la que podemos encontrar oraciones independientes introducidas por *que* es aquella en que la conjunción se encuentra combinada con marcadores discursivos. Para Muñoz Medrano (2005:251), en estos casos *que* se yuxtapone a marcadores discursivos que expresan modalidad:
>
> ```
>    (17) Mira que no haberte visto, mujer, en San Sebas: si allí nos conocemos todos (C. Martín Gaite, 2002: 38).
> ```
>
> 3.2.1.6. Un último caso a revisar será el denominado por Spitzer (1942: 105-126 en Porroche 2000: 103) como *que* narrativo, que Porroche (2000: 102) describe como aquel que es “obligatorio” y que se emplea para hacer referencia al discurso ajeno; por esta razón se le atribuye un valor metalingüístico. En Muñoz Medrano (2005: 247) también encontramos referencias al *que* narrativo de Spitzer, y a propósito de él se señala que “se caracteriza por la supresión del *verbum dicendi*, aportando así mayor vigor al discurso”:
>
> ```
>    (18) Los chicos me miraron y uno de ellos era Emilio. Se puso muy contento y me pasó un brazo por la espalda con familiaridad. Que qué casualidad, que dónde me metía, que se había acordado de mí tantas veces (C. Martín Gaite, 2002: 98).
> ```

Comment: querido Gustavson, muchísimas gracias =)